# A sharp change in rep: what did I do?

Tags: support

It says "voting corrected," but I hadn't noticed anything suspicious, and I'm pretty sure I haven't done any suspicious voting myself either. What gives?

Answer (score 4):

Check your [reputation change history](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/15261/ricky?tab=reputation). It's because of this:

[image]

At 13:53 server time yesterday, a user serial upvoted your posts a total of **19** times within the span of some 90 seconds. It is possible that whoever did this genuinely liked all of your posts, but regardless of motivation [Stack Exchange does not allow targeted voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260100/2940351) in either direction.

Accordingly the system periodically checks for and undo such behaviour. This occurred earlier today, and resulted in that -150 reversal you see. As long as you are not doing any of the serial voting (either up or down) yourself, there is nothing to be worried about. It wasn't due to anything you did.

For further reading see [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) for the official explanation, also linked to in the history.

Comment: Thank you. Hmm. Didn't know I had such a dedicated fan here. On a history forum of all places! Wow. Not that I don't deserve a few, but I'm of the opinion that upvotes should be accompanied by comments containing explanations.

Comment: The fella doth protest too much, methinks. After more self congratulation no less.